# Getting https to work on localhost node.js

Tags: node.js, https

Is there a way I can get my node.js app to run on `https://localhost:3000` instead of on the default `http://localhost:3000`? I need to add the additional https to test certain features.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use `express`, you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60947658/9585130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, head over to one of these links - **https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/https.html** or **https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/https.html**

Comment: To confirm, based on that link, I would put the key and cert in the directory `/app_name/test/fixtures/keys`, right?

Comment: You can put them wherever you want, just make sure path is correct.

Comment: thanks. and lastly, during the process to generate the key/cert, do i list `localhost` or `localhost:3000` as my domain name?